# Import a exploit into msfconsole on ubuntu

Tags: exploit, metasploit

I'm attending a offensive security courses and one of the subject is import a exploit from exploitdb into msfconsole. Commonly advice that it's required to create a exploit folder inside .msf4 and later put the exploit inside this folder; later you write the comand `sudo updatedb`. I did this, and the exploit did not show up. I tried to innovate and create a symbolic link from the metasploit directory: `opt/metasploit-framework/embedded/modules/exploits` (when almost all the examples explain the folder is `/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/exploits`) to `.msf4/modules/exploit` and was useless. I know all the examples and the websites basis in kali linux example, I have Ubuntu 20.04. So I need someone explain me how can I import a exploit into msfconsole on Ubuntu? or should I install kali linux on vmware virtual machine because it is not supported this option in ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

We don't have access to the strucutre of your filesystem but in general you need to make sure:

1. Your `.msf4` folder is in your home directory.
2. Your directory strucutre for the exploit corresponds to what is shown in Exploit-DB.

Short of seeing your filesystem ourselves, I am not totally sure anyone can help fix this issue. You don't **need** Kali. But having everything pre-installed does solve issues such as this (usually).

Comment: Thanks! I got a question: Is necesary the exploit only be a ruby file or can it be from other programing languages? i verify the things you've said previulsy and all is right. Mi msf4 folder is in root. I dont understand why the exploit doesn't show up

Comment: @GabrielAlejandroRivasMata Yes, it's necessary that it is a ruby file. msf is a ruby project and only works with ruby. Of course, you can create an executable in a different language and write a ruby wrapped for it.